# Session Input Less than 15 minutes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to reduce the time units in the input fields. As a standard, only 15-minute steps are possible in the input. I would like to have time selection in discrete minutes. Is that possible

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify the step of `input.session()`. However, it still accepts discrete values.

Or you can create some `input.string()` inputs and create a drop-down menu for all the possible options.

Just an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

sess_1 = input.session("0900-1400", "Session 1")
sess_1_start_h = input.string("01", "Session Start", ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"], inline="session_1_strat")
sess_1_start_m = input.string("03", ":", ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"], inline="session_1_strat")
sess_1_end_h = input.string("03", "Session End", ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"], inline="session_1_ennd")
sess_1_end_m = input.string("06", ":", ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"], inline="session_1_ennd")

plot(close)
```

[image]

Please note that the default value for *`Session 1`* is `0900-1400`. I just manually typed `09:23` and you won't have any problems with that.